# ValueError: Element locator 'id=Passwd' did not match any elements in gmail (robotframework, Pycharm)

Tags: gmail, pycharm, robotframework

I am using Mac EI Captain with Pycharm as IDE and Robotframework. I am getting an error

> ValueError: Element locator 'id=Passwd' did not match any elements.

This is only with the case of Gmail.com but not other websites. I used my same script for Facebook and Linkedin and it worked.

Here is my script:

```
Open Browser  https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier  firefox
Page Should Contain  Sign in to continue to Gmail
Input Text  id=Email  user
Click Button  id=next
Wait Until Page Contains  Sign in with a different account
Input Password  id=Passwd  fdsfs
Click Button  id=signIn
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking Next, wait for the password field to appear and then click on it to enable it. I added these lines to your test to make it work.

```
Wait Until Page Contains Element    id=Passwd
Click Element    id=Passwd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... u saved me!

Comment: Is it possible for you to tell me how do I use for loop to check another username and password? I am trying it for a long time but still not able to finish it. I will be grateful. Thanks!